# Why do babies say "Aua!"?

Tags: interjection

For me it's a surprise that babies articulate a double-syllable word do express pain, while pain is something spontaneous, and I guess it would be expressed by a single-syllable, or single vowel. So I asked somebody:

I had a conversation with a friend, who claims that *aua!* is completely natural, and isn't taught by the parents (tutors, nanny, older siblings or similar influence). *I doubt it*. If it were natural, then lot of babies in the world would say *aua!* when something hurts, and not only those of German speaking parents. (I even doubt babies' first word is *mama* because of easiness of the word, but because the mother expects the baby to say this and repeats him that word – I might be plain wrong, though).

Now, the parents don't say *aua!* when something hurts, but they expect the baby to say *aua!* when they read pain in the face of the baby (I guess), so they fake the *aua!* a baby is expected to do. So I guess the interjection is said by the babies only because the parents transmit it, isn't it? Does anybody have evidence showing the contrary?

Comment: Good question, but i guess you will only get opinion based answers here. If I were you, I would go to the linguistics site. Other than that, there seems to be something very universal about mama and -a..a patterns. Greek:mana/ Mama. Germanic: mama. Chinese: mama Japanese: Haha . This is Not the case for aua, which a Greek will not interpret as pain.

Comment: I've never heard a baby say "aua!" (they usually just cry). But small children do.

Comment: I have a baby right now and we surely didn't teach him to say "aua". Instead, he says it in many contexts. Currently it's his "word" for "pick me up and carry me" or "Somebody come and help me".

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar You surely never said to him "Oh, hast Du aua gemacht?" when he hurt himself somewhere?

Comment: @Matthias Yes, because that's not the way we talk to our kids :-) We'd say "Oh, hast Du dir weh getan?". He started it himself really. Or he picked it up from our older daughter. But he doesn't say when he's hurt, but when we wants our attention.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar But when he's using it this way, wouldn't it be an argument against _aua_ being a natural sound for being hurt? He might have learned it from his sister, seeing that she gets particular attention when she's using it.

Comment: @Matthias Well, my guess is that "aua" transitions from "give me attention" to "I'm hurt" or "something's wrong". I mean, our older daughter used it too, suddenly without us "teaching it". In general it is hard to tell what children just "pick up" - maybe they heard us say it when we hurt ourselves?

Comment: @Matthias You can argue, like Crissov, that there are natural baby sounds. But you can't argue that their meanings are mostly consistent. Any consistencies probably stem from the few number of things the baby talks about and from mama being his first interest.

Comment: @Ludi Finnish for *mum* is *äiti*. No real *a* sound. Okay, granted; that's a new word (i.e. last 2000 years). The original Finnish word is *emo*. Still no *a*s.

Comment: @Jan of course. You can't expect it to be a law :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

/a/ is the most sonorous human sound (and vowel), whereas /u/ is the least sonorous vowel, cf. “sonority hierarchy” or “sonority scale”. /au/ is therefore the “widest” diphthong possible. When acquiring speech, people tend to use and combine the extremes most. /ma/, for instance, has maximum contrast for [+sonorant]. We also prefer simple, open CV syllable like this and tend to reduplicate them, hence *mama*. *papa* actually has even larger internal contrast. For /aua/, it’s obviously not (full) reduplication. A lot of the words of “baby talk” can be explained thusly and many are international, although not necessarily with the same meaning.

- /da.da/ ‘daddy’
- /la.la/ ‘music’
- /bu.bu/ ‘sleep’
- /bæ.bæ/ ‘disgusting’
- /ʔi.ʔi/ ‘disgusting’
- /ka.ka/ ‘poo’
- /ʔa.ʔa/ ‘poo’
- /lu.lu/ ‘pee’
- /pi.pi/ ‘pee’; ‘penis’
- /po.po/ ‘behind’
- /mu.mu/ ‘vagina’; ‘cow’
- /mæ.mæ/ ‘sheep’
- /vau.vau/ ‘dog’
- /mʲau.mʲau/ ‘cat’
- /ʔo.ʔo/ ‘surprise’
- /hV.hV/ laughter
- …

Comment: JFTR I didn’t mention more complex (German) baby talk words like _Heia_ ‘sleep, bed’ or _Happa_ ‘eat, meal’.

Comment: Very good! Of all languages I speak, Greek seems most non conform in this context. But even they use many of these：mama, baba, jaja, kaka, popo...

Comment: I would extend your argument by adding /ai/ as a diphthong. That would capture languages as diverse as Japanese (*it**ai***) and Finnish (*ai* or *au*).

Answer (score 7):

I think you are right. *Aua* is children's speak, they learn it from their parents, who try to express in words what their children feel in a simple word that babies can soon use themselves.

I guess it is a children's version of [*Au*](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?bookref=1,598,30), about which Grimm's dictionary says

> **AU**, *ein schmerzensruf, dem sich schon mhd. wie heute ein* we *zugesellt, in welchem eigentlich die vorstellung des leides und wehes liegt.* au *scheint also aus dem vorangestellten ruf* ô *diphthongisch entfaltet*

So the word has old Germanic roots. Grimm's dictionary also lists the related *aubeia* (nowadays: auweia) and also *autsch* (to me a surprise, I'd have expected this word to be much younger).

Comment: In English "Ouch!" is a well known exclamation if you hurt yourself. It sounds pretty similar to "Autsch" - maybe it *is* just a natural sound to create when you hurt yourself, which then turns into a language specific "word"? In France children say "ai" instead of "au" - so I guess it's produced based on the general *sound of the language*.

Comment: Funny enough, Swedish speaking people also use "ai", despite it being a germanic language - and fairly close to German. Confusing :)